# CodeIgniter Cookie won't set but Session is working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I'm working with CodeIgniter to set up some user login functions to my site using Twitter and Facebook, this parts working and the session works fine.

When I try to set a cookie it doesn't work

```
//Setup a guid
$guid = uniqid();

//Setup a random cookie and point it to db user
$cookie = array(
  'name'   => 'TheCookieName',
  'value'  => $guid,
  'expire' => 100,
  'domain' => BASE_URL,
  'secure' => TRUE
);

    set_cookie($cookie);

  var_dump(get_cookie('TheCookieName')); // bool(false)
```

My autoload file is simple enough

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('paging_helper','url','cookie');
```

I'm obviously missing something trivial? Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably within your domain variable
BASE_URL, which isn't a part of CI constants, probably doesn't contain what you expect or what a cookie initialization requires.

Try doing it like this:

```
//Setup a guid
$guid = uniqid();

//Setup a random cookie and point it to db user
$cookie = array(
  'name'   => 'TheCookieName',
  'value'  => $guid,
  'expire' => 86500, // have a high cookie time till you make sure you actually set the cookie
  'domain' => '.example.org', // the first . to make sure subdomains isn't a problem
  'path' => '/',
  'secure' => TRUE
);

    set_cookie($cookie);
```

Remember that cookies will never be available until a new request have been made.
Redirect to another page on the domain specified in the cookie setup and check for the cookie again.

Comment: After setting the BASE_URL to nothing and letting CI figure it out, it worked but for some reason I had to call the function like -- set_cookie($param, $param, $param, $etc) instead of passing as an array. Don't know why but it works.

Comment: Sounds strange... You're sure your not using setcookie() instead of set_cookie()?

Comment: @Repox what should be in domain if we are testing our code at localhost/folder_name/ ?

Comment: @Aryans You should be safe without having to provide anything - any particular reason as to why you are changing that setting?

Comment: @Repox when I set my cookie it is setted and works fine but when i close the browser it lost as well, do't know why?

Comment: @Aryans This would call for some code and debugging. You would be better off by asking a new question on SO.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you set **secure => TRUE** for https only

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set and access a cookie in the same instance. You should either redirect after setting the cookie or refresh. That's the reason why var_dumping get_cookie would always return false. You should also set the rest of the arguments. 
See [setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie)

Comment: Even if i redirect the cookie is still false. Also please note the set_cookie() is a CodeIgniter function and not the native PHP setcookie()

Comment: @SeanHJenkins Can you try var_dumping $_COOKIE["TheCookieName"]