# set cookie is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, cookies

Hi I'm setting cookie in codeigniter and my code is

```
if(isset($inputData["rememberMe"])) {
     $cookieData = array(
          "name"   => "rememberMe",
          "value"  => 1,
          "expire" => 25000,
          "domain" => SITE_URL,
          "path"   => "/",
          "secure" => TRUE,
          "prefix" => "asi_"
     );
     $this->input->set_cookie($cookieData);
     echo '<pre>';print_r(get_cookie("asi_rememberMe"));echo '</pre>';
     echo '<pre>';print_r($this->input->cookie("asi_rememberMe"));echo '</pre>';
     die('Call');
}
```

and cookie helper is initialised in `autoload.php` file like this `$autoload['helper'] = array("url", "form", "cookie");` so no need to call helper in my controller and I've tried both ways to get cookie first is `get_cookie("asi_rememberMe")` and second is `$this->input->cookie("asi_rememberMe")` but both are not working and my codeigniter version is `3.1.5` don't know what is wrong with my code and I've also search different forums but didn't work for me.

Comment: You can't get info out of cookies until the next request when they're sent. Unsure if Codeigniter has stuff to account for this.

Comment: but the cookie is set now so it should retrieve the cookie?

Comment: No it's not. The cookie is on the client machine and they don't get the data until you've sent the current request's response. Then on the next request, the updated cookie data is sent.

Comment: The cookie can only be read after the next request. If you need the data before that, save it in some other way.

Comment: setcookie sends a cookie to the browser. You cannot access that cookie again until the browser sends it back to the server as part of the next page submission

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you show me the example code?

Comment: First off, you need to let us know who you're asking (write a @ directly followed by the users name to tag them in the comment). You also need to let us know what you want an example code of?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's more a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201570/codeigniter-cookie-wont-set-but-session-is-working?rq=1 rather than the one linked.

Comment: @63d26a1c Thanks, Added that to the list of answers

Comment: @RiggsFolly It means cookie is set now I can't get it until a new request have been made???

Comment: That is correct, when you submit the page it will be available in the script

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for reply...

Comment: @User8405526: This is the way HTTP works. *Setting a cookie* is just adding a header (`Set-Cookie`) in the response sent to the client. Then, the client will transmit it (and the other cookies, if applicable) in the header `Cookie` of any request matching the same domain (and path). The variable `$_COOKIES` reflects the cookies sent by the client in the request you are currently processing, that's why you need to wait for the next one to see the cookie you set.